# Why MySQL where in (list) takes quite long?

Tags: mysql

I try to use MySQL where in (list) where list is 1000 items. It takes me around 5 seconds. Is it normal?

My query look like this

```
select HEX(hash) as hash from hash_table where hash in (UNHEX("2C9ED97BB7CF48DDF74F"),....)
```

I have about 10 million rows in hash_table.

How could I make it faster?

Comment: I would say you are lucky at 5 seconds. If you are getting those respectable numbers, then, though you are running 1000 items thru a function in an `in clause`, you probably have hash indexed and are taking advantage of mysql CBO

Comment: Please add the table schema (create table statement)

Comment: There are lots of questions on here about query tuning. Go and have a look at the information provided in those that are resolved and the information not supplied in those which have been closed (table schema, data volumes, explain plan, profiling)